# Why is my node express route not found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am trying to add a route to '/signup' in my node express app. The GET to '/' is working, but '/signup' gives a 404 not found.

index.js and signup.js are both in the root folder.

signup.hbs and index.hbs are both in my views folder.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');
var signup = require('./signup');

const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.use('/signup', signup);
```

signup.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup', {text:"Send some text to template here"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

link in index.hbs (results in 404 not found):

```
<a style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;" href="/signup">Sign up</a>
```

Comment: Already tried to add your `res.render` inside of `function` after declare a `if (err) {  throw err; } ` and after the end `if throw err` perform the `res.render`?

Answer (score 0):

Modules in node.js are singletons by default, therefore loading a module more than once is unnecessary. 
If you want to consider index.js as the file that will load express.js, consider exporting the express variable you have defined and importing index.js in signup.js.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
...
module.exports{
    app
}
```

**signup.js**

```
const index = require('./index');
...
const router = index.app.Router();
```

Also, seems like your use of `app.use` is kinda off. You should provide a router, an express app or make your own middleware, while you are just sending a module (signup.js). You can read more about it here: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples

Comment: Previously my index.js ended in: `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`. I tried modifying with module.exports as outlined above, but index.app.Router returns "cannot read property Router of undefined".

Comment: I just checked that, without rendering views, your routing works just fine (I just sent some object instead). Therefore, the problem might be locating the views. Assuming the `view` folder is in the root folder, you could try this: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`
Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

 router.post('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('signup', {OCR:"OCR TEXT"});
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Server is not finding appropriate method call so it is sending your 404 page .

you have to use POST method on your route , If you are sending some data to server

Comment: I'm actually not sending any data on this request. I simply want to do a GET request to bring the user to the signup page. I'm assuming <a href> performs a GET request.

Comment: A regular link **does** trigger a GET request.